# Webpack: How to export JS file without module

Tags: webpack

I have a js file that looks like this:

```
self.MonacoEnvironment = {
  baseUrl: CDN_HOST + '/javascripts'
};
importScripts('/javascripts/vs/base/worker/workerMain.js');
```

In my webpack.config, I have CDN_HOST defined:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'CDN_HOST': JSON.stringify(process.env.CDN_HOST || '')
}),
enter code here
```

I would like to export this file, but have `CDN_HOST` get replaced with the value here, but I do NOT want this file to be wrapped in a module (e.g, "webpackjsonP")

If i use `file-loader` then it will copy the file with module definitions, but not replace `CDN_HOST`.

If i use `babel-loader`, then it will replace `CDN_HOST` but add the module definitions.

How can I just use `DefinePlugin` but not use Modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this without using `DefinePlugin`.  Instead, I used `file-loader` chained with `string-replace-loader`.  `string-replace-loader` is nearly equivalent to `DefinePlugin` for my purposes.

```
loaders: [
    "file-loader?name=./filetoexport.js",
    {
      loader: "string-replace-loader",
      query: {

        search: 'CDN_HOST',
        replace: JSON.stringify(process.env.CDN_HOST || '')
      }
    },
  ]
```